# Altium diagram output for various clients

Tags: altium, output

question regarding the usage of Altium 10

Detailed:
2 clients that have access to some project diagrams. They are both aware that others use them. However when they get the diagram they want their own drawing head template to be used. Is it possible to somehow manufacturer an output of the core design but with 2 different Company names / logos in the drawing head? Copy the main project folder, leaves two identical core designs which have to  be maintained and updated. Accidents waiting to happen.

Any idea or other ways to do this.

Comment: Seems like all you need are two templates (one per client) that are the same sheet size but with unique drawing head blocks. Just apply different templates depending on which client you're providing the schematic to

Answer (score 1):

I see two major ways of doing it:

1. Update the template for each client as mentioned above in the comments and seen below. This may be scriptable as well, as I don't think OutJobs let you directly change the template per output.

[image]

2. Run without a template, or a template that has placeholder imagery, and then post-process the PDF to add the appropriate logo / imagery. Some Python libraries should be able to support this.